# Can't unwrap Optional.None when setting window background color

Tags: swift, xcode6

I think I'm missing something very simple here...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.window.backgroundColor = NSColor.grayColor();                            
}
```

This returns

```
fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None
```

which isn't a very descriptive error. Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something in the `self.view.window.backgroundColor` chain (probably `self.view.window`) is nil. Many view- and view controller-related properties are implemented as implicitly unwrapped, which means that they are Optionals that you can treat like non-Optional variables for convenience's sake. Unfortunately, if you try to access one when it's nil you get the runtime error you're seeing.

Can you set the background color of the view's layer instead? `view.window` is nil when a view hasn't been added to a window, but `view.layer` should be there regardless.

Comment: After reading that I moved that line of code to viewWillAppear(), thinking that it should be fully loaded by that stage, and it worked. Thanks!