# "Can't unwrap Optional.None" and I can't figure out why

Tags: swift

This produces "fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None" and I don't seem to get why

```
var motionManager = CMMotionManager()
motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.2
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
var accelerationData = motionManager.accelerometerData
var accel = accelerationData.acceleration.x
```

If anyone can help me out, that would be great.

Comment: I want to figure out the x value of the acceleration but I can't figure out how to do it. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: None is None (brought in from Obj-C as nil). How can get a property of None?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006287/cant-unwrap-optional-none , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132010/cant-unwrap-optional-none?rq=1

Comment: `accelerationData` is nil! please check!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_428

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is accelerationData is nil and you aren't checking for this. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMMotionManager/accelerometerData):

> If no accelerometer data is available, the value of this property is nil.

You should check to make sure there is actually data before calling methods on it like this

```
if let accelerationData = motionManager.accelerometerData {
    var accel = accelerationData.acceleration.x
}
```

That will ensure that if there is no data your app won't crash. Now to make sure you get some data.

You aren't getting any data because you're asking for data immediately after you initialize the core motion manager. You can show this by waiting a few seconds before checking. You can add `NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(3)` right above the if let and run the project and it will enter the if let. Make sure you are using an actual device though, the simulator won't generate any motion data.